# Dynamically change polygon position in cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to draw few polygons that dynamically change their position.

The problem is that by using:

```
onUpdatePolygonData(data){

/// DO SOME CALCULATIONS TO GET point1, point2 point3...

if(Cesium.defined(entity.polygon)
     entity.polygon.hierarchy = new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy([point1, point2, point3])  
else entity.polygon = viewer.entities.add({ 
     polygon = new Cesium.PolygonGraphics({
          hierarchy: new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy([point1, point2, point3])
     })
});
}
```

The result is disturbing blinking on the map.

Updating location occurs roughly once in 40ms though seems like frequency of updates have nothing to do with it.

Anyone knows a way to make the changes smoother?

Thanks for help,
David.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code sample, that shows the update etc?

Comment: Is that more helpful now?
Fortunately I'm not next to my code for the coming few weeks, so i wrote what i remembered.

Comment: Hi, does anyone have any ideas regarding my problem?

Thanks in advance, David

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Callbackproperty, it executed every frame so it won't blink and be smoother.

In typescript you can write:

```js
let poly = viewer.entities.add({
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: new CallbackProperty (() => {
              return new PolygonHierarchy([point1, point2, 
        point3]) ;
        }, false) 
});
```

Comment: Of course for performance it will be better to store one polygonhierarchy instance, and in the callbackproperty to mutate his position.