# Cesium polygon callback using javascript

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to edit the change the edit or redraw the polygon. this is my code.
Error

```
An error occurred while rendering.  Rendering has stopped.
TypeError: this._callback is not a function
TypeError: this._callback is not a function
```

using `pickedObject.id` i got the exect polygon i want to reposition, but call back issue.

```
var points = [-95.8079865631313, 30.24038650541154, -
    60.10509002138564, 23.526593580490083, -59.06372427570612, 2.245934026097194, -
    117.00668212362282, 3.938434130034481
];

function loadPoly(points) {

    redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
        id: "myArray",
        name: "myArray",
        polygon: {
            hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(points),
            material: Cesium.Color.fromBytes(221, 240, 235, 160)
        }
    });
    polygonCollection.push(redPolygon);

    adding_billboard(-95.8079865631313, 30.24038650541154, "A", "-95.8079865631313, 30.24038650541154");
    adding_billboard(-60.10509002138564, 23.526593580490083, "A", "-60.10509002138564, 23.526593580490083");
    adding_billboard(-59.06372427570612, 2.245934026097194, "A", "-59.06372427570612, 2.245934026097194");
    adding_billboard(-117.00668212362282, 3.938434130034481, "A", "-117.00668212362282, 3.938434130034481");

    viewer.flyTo(redPolygon);

}

function adding_billboard(lon, lat, name, popup) {
    var entity = viewer.entities.add({

        name: name,
        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat, 2000),
        billboard: {
            image: 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png',
            show: true, // default
            pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -20), // default: (0, 0)
            eyeOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), // default
            horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.bottom, // default               
            alignedAxis: Cesium.Cartesian3.ZERO, // default
            width: 20, // default: undefined
            height: 25, // default: undefined
            //disableDepthTestDistance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, // draws the label in front of terrain
            // on ground show


        },
        label: {
            text: popup,
            font: "7pt sans-serif",
            heightReference: Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
            horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.LEFT,
            verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BASELINE,
            fillColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
            showBackground: true,
            backgroundColor: new Cesium.Color(1, 1, 1, 0.7),
            backgroundPadding: new Cesium.Cartesian2(8, 4),
            disableDepthTestDistance: Number
                .POSITIVE_INFINITY, // draws the label in front of terrain
        },

    });
    pointsCollection.push(entity);
}

var coordinates = [76.82071632075994, 33.4134542888633, 77.83750798568438, 33.39276536442791, 77.32892923803021,
    32.93547457354476
];

var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
handler.setInputAction(function(click) {

    var pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);
    if (Cesium.defined(pickedObject)) {

        console.log("Second ");
        console.log("pickedObject.id.id ", pickedObject.id.id);
        console.log("pickedObject.id.name ", pickedObject.id.name);
        console.log("pickedObject.id..polygon.hierarchy ", pickedObject.id.polygon.hierarchy.valueOf());
        var data = pickedObject.id.polygon.hierarchy.valueOf();
        console.log("data ", data.positions.valueOf());
        pickedObject.id.polygon = {
            hierarchy: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(coordinates),
                false),
            material: Cesium.Color.fromBytes(221, 240, 235, 160)
        
        //pickedObject.id = redPolygon;// tried this but dailed due to same id then i removed it.
        if (pickedObject.id.name == 'C') {
            // $('#modal-activity').modal('show');
        }
    }
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```

i want to shift polygon to some other coordiante but unable to use call back properly can some one guild me how can I do ?
i did some google searches which are given below but my issues not solved.

here i was trying to make polygon points dynamic but line disappers in tarrains. fist time it was ok after moving point it disappers.
https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?#c=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

second :[Dynamically change polygon position in cesium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476302/dynamically-change-polygon-position-in-cesium)

it also gives error because i don't know where to use callback.
please guild me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

```
const {
    Cartesian3,
    CallbackProperty,
    Color,
    defined,
    ScreenSpaceEventHandler,
    ScreenSpaceEventType,
    Viewer
} = window.Cesium;

const viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer");

let redPolygon;
const polygonCollection = [];
const pointsCollection = [];
const polygonId = "myArray";

let polygonPoints = [
    -95.8079865631313, 30.24038650541154, -60.10509002138564, 23.526593580490083, -59.06372427570612,
    2.245934026097194, -117.00668212362282, 3.938434130034481
];

function loadPoly() {
    redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
        id: polygonId,
        name: "myArray",
        polygon: {
            hierarchy: new CallbackProperty(() => {
                return {
                    positions: Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(polygonPoints)
                };
            }, false),
            material: Color.fromBytes(221, 240, 235, 160)
        }
    });

    polygonCollection.push(redPolygon);

    adding_billboard(-95.8079865631313, 30.24038650541154, "A", "-95.8079865631313, 30.24038650541154");
    adding_billboard(-60.10509002138564, 23.526593580490083, "A", "-60.10509002138564, 23.526593580490083");
    adding_billboard(-59.06372427570612, 2.245934026097194, "A", "-59.06372427570612, 2.245934026097194");
    adding_billboard(-117.00668212362282, 3.938434130034481, "A", "-117.00668212362282, 3.938434130034481");

    viewer.flyTo(redPolygon);
}

function adding_billboard(lon, lat, name, popup) {
    const entity = viewer.entities.add({
        name: name,
        position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat, 2000),
        billboard: {
            image: "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png",
            show: true, // default
            pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -20), // default: (0, 0)
            eyeOffset: new Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), // default
            horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.bottom, // default
            alignedAxis: Cesium.Cartesian3.ZERO, // default
            width: 20, // default: undefined
            height: 25 // default: undefined
            //disableDepthTestDistance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, // draws the label in front of terrain
            // on ground show
        },
        label: {
            text: popup,
            font: "7pt sans-serif",
            heightReference: Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
            horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.LEFT,
            verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BASELINE,
            fillColor: Color.BLACK,
            showBackground: true,
            backgroundColor: new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.7),
            backgroundPadding: new Cesium.Cartesian2(8, 4),
            disableDepthTestDistance: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY // draws the label in front of terrain
        }
    });

    pointsCollection.push(entity);
}

loadPoly();

const scene = viewer.scene;
const handler = new ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);

handler.setInputAction(function (click) {
    const pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);

    if (defined(pickedObject) && pickedObject.id && pickedObject.id.id === polygonId) {
        const newPolygonPoints = [
            76.82071632075994, 33.4134542888633, 77.83750798568438, 33.39276536442791, 77.32892923803021,
            32.93547457354476
        ];

        polygonPoints = newPolygonPoints;

        viewer.camera.flyTo({
            destination: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(76.82071632075994, 33.4134542888633, 1000)
        });
    }
}, ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```

Comment: thank you so much, it workes perfectly. we just need to chnage the ```newPolygonPoints```

Comment: can we give polygon values like array of 2D arrays like instead of this
``let polygonPoints = [
    -95.8079865631313, 30.24038650541154, -60.10509002138564, 23.526593580490083, -59.06372427570612,
    2.245934026097194, -117.00668212362282, 3.938434130034481
];```
we use ```polygonPoints= [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[3,4]]``` some thing like this can we ?

Comment: not. please check Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray 's usage in https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Cartesian3.html?classFilter=Cartesian3.

Comment: yes i saw that wasnot able to do. my Aim is to when i move Billboard; Polygon also should move where billboard is. i want to make Dynamic Polygon. so can you give me any suggestion how that.
currently i am able to move billboard. but polygon points donot move along with billboard.

Comment: how can we add multiple polygon by this method because if i change coordiantes ```polygonPoints``` the polygon will shift there. how can i give coordaintes to specfic polygon with some ID.